# Keeping a connection open for the purposes of testing

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to conduct a database test where I run a transaction set against the database while having X number of idle connections open to the database. That being said, I have started to create some logic for opening connections to the database as such:

```
import socket

def open_connect(hostname, port):
  """Function that creates a socket connection

  :hostname: Hostname to connect to.
  :port: Port to connect to host on.

  """
  ipaddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  sock.connect((ipaddr, port))
  sock.close()

def main():
  """Main function."""
  open_connect('somedb', 3306)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

What I need to add now is some logic that will keep the connection open during the duration of the test. Can someone please provide guidance on the best way to keep a db connection open while I run actual queries in parallel? This will meet my test objectives. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might not want to use Sockets. I would try using a library like MySQLdb.

```
import MySQLdb

# connect
con = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="appuser", passwd="",db="onco")
```

You would be able to check if the connections is up using the ping method:

```
def is_connection_up(connection):
    if connection.ping() == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

So you can do something like this:

```
import MySQLdb
import time

def is_connection_up(connection):
    if connection.ping() == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

host,user,pwd,db = "localhost","user","pwd","db"
connections = [MySQLdb.connect(host=host,user=user,passwd=pwd,db=db) for i in range(10)]

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    for con in connections:
        if is_connection_up(con) is not True:
            raise Exception("Connection is down, test might have gone wrong")
```

Comment: This is great, and will get me started. Thank you!